# Actualization with Vlookup in Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have two tables, table2 in Sheet2 and table1 in Sheet1. I need to calculate the "vf" column
in table1. All values are random, except for vf which is a function of all other values (Formula below). The actual formula works fine but I have to enlarge the table2 till column 100 (in this example with other randomic values). The problem is: how can I rewrite the formula for "vf" in order to be shorter and understandable when I will have to add 100 columns to the table2?

The Formula to create "vf":

```
=IF(AND(A2="s2",E2>1),(C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,2,FALSE)+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,3,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^2)*(IF(E2>=2,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,4,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^3)*(IF(E2>=3,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,5,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^4)*(IF(E2>=4,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,6,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^5)*(IF(E2>=5,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,7,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^6)*(IF(E2>=6,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,8,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^7)*(IF(E2>=7,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,9,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^8)*(IF(E2>=8,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,10,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^9)*(IF(E2>=9,1,0))+C2*D2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,11,FALSE)*(1/(1+F2)^10)*(IF(E2>=10,1,0))),C2*D2*H2*VLOOKUP(G2,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7,2,FALSE))
```

Table1 in Sheet1:

[image]

Table2 in Sheet2:

[image]

Sort of pseudo code (c++ style) to translate in VBA:

```
double VF(std::string c1, int year, double v1, double v2, double v3, double v4, double v5) {

    double vf = 0; //initialize vf
    int initialtableLookUpColumnNo = 2;

    if ((c1 == "s2") && (v2 > 1)) {   
        for (int i=initialtableLookUpColumnNo; i=v2+1; i++) {
            vf += vlookup(v4, Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7, i, FALSE) * v0 * v1 * (1/(1+v3)**(i-1));
        }      
    }
    else {
        vf += vlookup(v4, Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7, 2, FALSE) * v0 * v1 * v5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend creating a 'custom function' (aka vba function). Likely not as fast (in processing time), but more readily understandable and therefore more readily adaptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the best solution here is to make an UDF function with VBA. I'll post the steps and code to be exhaustive for someone like me who doesn't know VBA.

1. Click Alt+11 to enter Visual Basic for Applications
2. Click Insert Module
3. Write the following code:

   [image]

Note that the order of the parameters in the function is at your discretion and you can also specify the type of the parameter such as: c1 as String, v2 as Integer, v5 as Double.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove vlookups from the formula.  You can place them in a new seperate column.  Then rewrite your formula by replacing vlookups with references to new column.

After this, convert your new formula into a built-in function.

You can name this function as `Vf` or something you like.  And in excel sheet delete your long formula and type your new function with its parameters like: `=Vf(A2,C2,D2,G2,F2)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, then, will I have to have a column for each vlookup present in the formula? is there no way to avoid this? Also, can you please give me an idea of this built-in function? (I'm not experienced with VBA).

Comment: Yes, you need to add a column for each vlookup.  There should be ways to avoid this but I cannot recommend anything more as I do not have info about the complexity and the size of the fixed values you are trying to get via vlookup.  For built-in function please google it, not that complex.

Comment: What you need to know about the size and complexity? The are simply =RAND(). I really appreciated the effort but with this solution we are moving the problem from having a formula that is too long to having a sheet full of useless columns (even if they can be hidden). I was already thinking about creating a function (in VBA) based on the parameters of the "vf" formula starting from a function created in C ++. I just wanted someone to write me a function similar to the one I had thought of in order to simplify the problem.

Comment: If your data in Sheet2!$A$2:$K$7 consists of just RAND()s, then you do not need to add extra columns.  Passing the parameter into function like rand(..) will work.   i.e. `=Vf(A2,C2,D2,G2,F2, RAND(something))`

Comment: what about the case `A2="s1"`

Comment: I have added in the question above a sort of c++ style pseudo code; the problem is that I do not know how to translate to VBA syntax